# Как задать/добавить стиль родительскому li в зависимости от вложенного input

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

У меня есть такие пункты

Красный(5)

Синий(0)

Черный(4)

Зависимость у меня только одна это строки 4, 14 и 23

```html
<div class="oiu">
<ul class="woof_list woof_list_checkbox">                     
  <li class="woof_term_37 ">
  <div class="icheckbox_flat-blue" >
  <input type="checkbox" id="woof_37_5ddabd90b31f1" class="woof_checkbox_term woof_checkbox_term_37" data-tax="pa_zvet" name="asdf" data-term-id="37" value="37">
  <ins class="iCheck-helper"></ins>
  </div>
  <label class="woof_checkbox_label " for="woof_37_5ddabd90b31f1">Красный<span class="woof_checkbox_count">(5)</span>
  </label>
  <input type="hidden" value="Красный" data-anchor="woof_n_pa_zvet_red">
  </li>

  <li class="woof_term_35 " >
  <div class="icheckbox_flat-blue disabled" style="position: relative;">
  <input type="checkbox" disabled="" id="woof_35_5ddabd90b4de9" class="woof_checkbox_term woof_checkbox_term_35" data-tax="pa_zvet" name="qwer" data-term-id="35" value="35" >
  <ins class="iCheck-helper"></ins>
  </div>
  <label class="woof_checkbox_label " for="woof_35_5ddabd90b4de9">Синий<span class="woof_checkbox_count">(0)</span>
  </label>
  <input type="hidden" value="Синий" data-anchor="woof_n_pa_zvet_blue">
  </li>
  <li class="woof_term_38 ">
  <div class="icheckbox_flat-blue" style="position: relative;">
  <input type="checkbox" id="woof_38_5ddabd90b541b" class="woof_checkbox_term woof_checkbox_term_38" data-tax="pa_zvet" name="zxcvv" data-term-id="38" value="38">
  <ins class="iCheck-helper"></ins>
  </div>
  <label class="woof_checkbox_label " for="woof_38_5ddabd90b541b">Черный<span class="woof_checkbox_count">(4)</span>
  </label>
  <input type="hidden" value="Черный" data-anchor="woof_n_pa_zvet_black">
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

или тут  - https://jsfiddle.net/gkan10qr/44/

мы имеем  разные `name=`, т.е. мы имеем несколько `name=`

- name="qwer"
- name="asdf"
- name="zxcv"

Нужно к этим li добавить класс

```
    <li class="woof_term_37">
....
    <li class="woof_term_35">
....
    <li class="woof_term_38">
....
```

добавить класс в зависимости от вложенного ИНПУТ
чтобы соответственно получилось

```
    <li class="woof_term_37 qwer">
....
    <li class="woof_term_35 asdf">
....
    <li class="woof_term_38 zxcv">
....
```

чтобы можно было применять  стили типа

```
    .woof_term_35.asdf {
    background: #F44336; 
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px; 
    }
    .woof_term_37.qwer {
    background: #333; 
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px; 
    }
    .woof_term_38.zxcv {
    background: #4CAF50; 
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;   
    }
```

Чтобы скрипт прописывать не для каждого блока li  `....35  ....37 ....38`, 
а какбы одной функцией  для `.woof_term_...`

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так, если с jquery:

```
$('.woof_list > li').each(element => {
    let name = $(element).find('input').attr('name');
    $(element).addClass('name');
});
```